# How to update tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-label

So I'm trying to make some sort of basic auto clicker with a rank that updates after a certain amount of clicks, but whenever I update the rank the label that is supposed to display it doesn't change and I don't know how to make the label update

```
from tkinter import *

count = 0
rank = "click the button to rank up!"

window = Tk()

if count == 1:
    rank = "wow first click!"

def click():
    global count
    count += 1
    counter = Label(window, text=count).grid(row = 0, column = 1)

clicker = Button(window, text="The Button", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = click).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

rankDisplay = Label(window, text = rank, padx = 100, pady = 25).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
  
window.mainloop()
```

after clicking for the first time, the rank is still displayed as "click the button to rank up" instead of "wow first click", and that's pretty much the issue

Comment: the if statement will be executed immediately, also you don't need to create a label each time a function is called and you are actually making it incorrectly (as with others, because layout manager methods return None), you simply need to `.config()` the widget instance, for example, just grid the button immediately but don't specify text (or use 0 as starting text), then simply do `label_instance.config(text=new_text)`

Comment: oh ok yeah that makes sense, I guess I was just thinking about it the wrong way, thanks for the awnser!

Answer (score 1):

I already knew this problem. To solve this, you have to create a global variable to your label :

```
global l1
l1 = Label(...)
```

Then, to modify the text, you have to do in your fonction :

```
l1.config(text=str(count))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is code:

```
from tkinter import *

count = 0

window = Tk()
def changed(text):
    rankDisplay.config(text=text)
    rankDisplay.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
def click():
    global count
    count += 1
    counter = Label(window, text=count).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    if count == 1:
        changed("wow first click!")
    return count
clicker = Button(window, text="The Button", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = click).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
rankDisplay = Label(window, text = "", padx = 100, pady = 25)
changed("click the button to rank up!")
  
window.mainloop()
```

When you click the button then label text is update "click buttton to rank up" to "wow first click".Because The text of label is a StringVar() and if I set the stringvar then the text of label is update to stringvar

Comment: So if you click this button then it update label "click button to rank up" to "wow first click"

Comment: You should update the question with explanation

Answer (score 0):

See here you should use the `update` method for the label named `rankDisplay`

here is the code :

```
from tkinter import *

count = 0



window = Tk()

rank = StringVar()
rank.set("Click the button to rank up")


def click():
    global count
    count += 1
    counter = Label(window, text=count).grid(row=0, column=1)
    if count == 1:
        rank.set("wow first click!")
        rankDisplay.update()


clicker = Button(window, text="The Button", padx=50, pady=50, command=click).grid(row=0, column=0)

rankDisplay = Label(window, textvariable=rank, padx=100, pady=25)
rankDisplay.grid(row=1, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Modifications in your code:
you should know the concept of `StringVar` in tkinter to use the `update` method.. link to know it [https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/#:~:text=The%20Tkinter%20StringVar%20helps%20you,Label%20or%20Entry%20more%20effectively.&text=The%20StringVar%20constructor%20accepts%20three,defaults%20to%20the%20root%20window](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/#:%7E:text=The%20Tkinter%20StringVar%20helps%20you,Label%20or%20Entry%20more%20effectively.&text=The%20StringVar%20constructor%20accepts%20three,defaults%20to%20the%20root%20window).

and in the `rankDisplay` label you have to use `textvariable` attribute instead of `text`

only these are the changes...

Answer (score 0):

Just added `rankDisplay.configure(...)` in line 16.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

count = 0
rank = "click the button to rank up!"

window = Tk()

#if count == 1:
    #rank = "wow first click!"

def click():
    global count
    count += 1
    counter = Label(window, text=count)
    counter.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    rankDisplay.configure(text="wow first click!")

clicker = Button(window, text="The Button", padx = 50, pady = 50, command = click).grid(row = 0, column = 0)

rankDisplay = Label(window, text = rank, padx = 100, pady = 25)
rankDisplay.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
  
window.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Output after clicking:

[image]